# Error while using useState hook in form in react

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, multer, use-state

I have following issue while running the code, need some help as I am not able to find out what is the issue even after finding out it for last 4 days.

1st- as per my product_specs hook , it is array of two input fields namely specification field and value filed, and 1 field of each should be present from start when "http://localhost:3000/productupload" page loads, but I am not getting these two filed from the start.
Note -addClick and Remove Click handler adds or remove this two input fields dynamically.
Image of web page when form loads is attached below.
[image]
2nd- when I type in my sub_category field I get errror
TypeError: Cannot set property 'sub_category' of undefined
[image]

My code for productupload page is

```
import FormInput from "../Forminput/forminput";
import CustomButton from "../Custombutton/custombutton";
import axios from "axios";

const ProductUpload = () => {
  const [sub_category, setSub_category] = useState("");

  const [product_name, setProduct_name] = useState("");

  const [product_image, setProduct_image] = useState("");

  const [product_specs, setProduct_specs] = useState([
    {
      specification: "",
      specvalue: "",
    },
  ]);
  
  const imageSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    setProduct_image({ product_image: event.target.files[0] });
  };

  // const imageUploadHandler = () => {
  //   const fd = new FormData();
  //   fd.append("product_image", product_image, product_image.name); //.name is Imp as name is property of file
  // };

  const handleChange = (e, i) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setSub_category({ ...sub_category, [name]: value });
    setProduct_name({ ...product_name, [name]: value });
    const p_specs = [...product_specs];
    product_specs[i][name] = value;
    setProduct_specs(p_specs); //This is 100% right.
  };
  //to add extra input field
  const addClick = () => {
    // setProduct_specs([...product_specs, { specification: "", specvalue: "" }]); //this is 100% right
    //also 100% correct alternative to above line
    const p_specs = [...product_specs];
    p_specs.push({ specification: "", specvalue: "" });
    setProduct_specs(p_specs);
  };
  //to remove extra input field
  const removeClick = (i) => {
    const p_specs = [...product_specs];
    p_specs.splice(i, 1);
    setProduct_specs(p_specs);
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newProduct = {
      sub_category,
      product_name,
      product_image,
      product_specs,
    };
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify(newProduct);
      const res = await axios.post("/api/product", body, config);
      console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.response.data);
    }
  };

  const createUI = () => {
    product_specs.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i} className="inputgroup">
          <FormInput
            type="text"
            name="specification"
            handleChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
            value={item.specification}
            label="specification"
            required
            customwidth="300px"
          ></FormInput>
          <FormInput
            type="text"
            name="specvalue"
            handleChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
            value={item.specvalue}
            label="specification values seperated by quomas"
            required
          ></FormInput>
          <CustomButton
            onClick={() => removeClick(i)}
            type="button"
            value="remove"
            style={{ margin: "12px" }}
          >
            Remove
          </CustomButton>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form
        action="/upload"
        method="post"
        className="form"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        encType="multipart/form-data"
      >
        <h3 style={{ color: "roboto, sans-serif" }}>
          Add new product to the database
        </h3>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            height: "200px",
            width: "200px",
            border: "2px solid #DADCE0",
            borderRadius: "6px",
            position: "relative",
          }}
        >
          <input
            // style={{ display: "none" }}
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            onChange={imageSelectedHandler}
            multiple={false}
            name="product_image"
          />
          {/* <CustomButton >
            Select Image
          </CustomButton>
          <CustomButton
          //  onClick={imageUploadHandler}
          >
            Upload
          </CustomButton> */}

          {/*as per brad- type = "submit" value="submit"  this should not be used, file should upload with the form submit */}
          <div>
            <img
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
              }}
              alt="#"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <FormInput
          type="text"
          name="sub_category"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={sub_category}
          label="select from subcategories"
          required
        ></FormInput>
        <FormInput
          type="text"
          name="product_name"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={product_name}
          label="product name"
          required
        ></FormInput>
        {createUI()}
        <div>
          <CustomButton
            onClick={addClick}
            type="button"
            style={{ margin: "14px" }}
          >
            Add More Fields
          </CustomButton>
          <CustomButton type="submit" style={{ margin: "12px" }}>
            Upload Product
          </CustomButton>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductUpload;
```

code in my product route(using express and multer for image upload

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const GridFsStorage = require("multer-gridfs-storage");
const multer = require("multer");
const connectDB = require("../../config/db");

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  db: connectDB(),
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
module.exports = upload;
// @route GET api/Product
// @desc Test route
// @acess Public
router.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Product route"));

// @route GET api/Product
// @desc staff will upload product to database
// @acess Private
router.post(
  "/",
  [
    check("subcategory", "subcategory is required").not().isEmpty(),
    check("product name", "product name is required").not().isEmpty(),
  ],
  upload.single("product_image"),
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const {
      sub_category,
      product_name,
      product_image,
      product_specs,
    } = req.body;

    try {
      //See if product exists
      let product = await Product.findOne({ product_name }); // Product.findOne() is mongo db query

      if (product) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ errors: [{ msg: "Product already exists" }] });
      }

      //New product instance will be created and once user.save() command is given user will be created in mongodb database.
      product = new Product({
        sub_category,
        product_name,
        product_image,
        product_specs,
      });

      await product.save();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send("Server error");
    }
  }
);
module.exports = router;
```

Please help me, I am stuck at this for 4 days. Please.

Comment: - `product_specs[i][name] = value;` should be read as `p_specs[i][name] = value;`

Comment: also you call `handleChange` like this `handleChange={handleChange}` and you do not send `i` parameter, so I yealds to `undefined` so `product_specs[i]` will be undefined

Comment: @karianpour ok I understood, but I want my all 3 states i.e sub_category, product_name, product_specs to update by handleChange , and product_specs need 2 argument (e,i) and other two dont require, How to handle this issue can you provide the solution to handle this situation. It will be a freat help.

Comment: You have to separate the `handleChange` which I saw that you already did in the answer.

Comment: @karianpour thank you for your time, I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you
for your response guys, I found the solution. Sharing you my final code here. Thanks

```
import FormInput from "../Forminput/forminput";
import CustomButton from "../Custombutton/custombutton";
import axios from "axios";

const ProductUpload = () => {
  const [sub_category, setSub_category] = useState({ sub_category: "" });

  const [product_name, setProduct_name] = useState({ product_name: "" });

  const [product_image, setProduct_image] = useState("");

  const [product_specs, setProduct_specs] = useState([
    {
      specification: "",
      specvalue: "",
    },
  ]);
  //note VIMP to add square bracket for array
  const imageSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    setProduct_image({ product_image: event.target.files[0] });
  };

  // const imageUploadHandler = () => {
  //   const fd = new FormData();
  //   fd.append("product_image", product_image, product_image.name); //.name is Imp as name is property of file
  // };
  const handleChange1 = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setSub_category({ ...sub_category, [name]: value });
    setProduct_name({ ...product_name, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleChange2 = (e, i) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    const p_specs = [...product_specs];
    p_specs[i][name] = value;
    setProduct_specs(p_specs); //This is 100% right.
  };

  //to add extra input field
  const addClick = () => {
    // setProduct_specs([...product_specs, { specification: "", specvalue: "" }]); //this is 100% right
    //also 100% correct alternative to above line
    const p_specs = [...product_specs];
    p_specs.push({ specification: "", specvalue: "" });
    setProduct_specs(p_specs);
  };
  //to remove extra input field
  const removeClick = (i) => {
    const p_specs = [...product_specs];
    p_specs.splice(i, 1);
    setProduct_specs(p_specs);
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newProduct = {
      sub_category,
      product_name,
      product_image,
      product_specs,
    };
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify(newProduct);
      const res = await axios.post("/api/product", body, config);
      console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.response.data);
    }
  };

  const createUI = () => {
    return product_specs.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i} className="inputgroup">
          <FormInput
            type="text"
            name="specification"
            handleChange={(e) => handleChange2(e, i)}
            value={item.specification}
            label="specification"
            required
            customwidth="300px"
          ></FormInput>
          <FormInput
            type="text"
            name="specvalue"
            handleChange={(e) => handleChange2(e, i)}
            value={item.specvalue}
            label="specification values seperated by quomas"
            required
          ></FormInput>
          <CustomButton
            onClick={() => removeClick(i)}
            type="button"
            value="remove"
            style={{ margin: "12px" }}
          >
            Remove
          </CustomButton>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form
        action="/upload"
        method="post"
        className="form"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        encType="multipart/form-data"
      >
        <h3 style={{ color: "roboto, sans-serif" }}>
          Add new product to the database
        </h3>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            height: "200px",
            width: "200px",
            border: "2px solid #DADCE0",
            borderRadius: "6px",
            position: "relative",
          }}
        >
          <input
            // style={{ display: "none" }}
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            onChange={imageSelectedHandler}
            multiple={false}
            name="product_image"
          />
          {/* <CustomButton >
            Select Image
          </CustomButton>
          <CustomButton
          //  onClick={imageUploadHandler}
          >
            Upload
          </CustomButton> */}

          {/*as per brad- type = "submit" value="submit"  this should not be used, file should upload with the form submit */}
          <div>
            <img
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
              }}
              alt="#"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <FormInput
          type="text"
          name="sub_category"
          handleChange={handleChange1}
          value={sub_category.sub_category}
          label="select from subcategories"
          required
        ></FormInput>

        <FormInput
          type="text"
          name="product_name"
          handleChange={handleChange1}
          value={product_name.product_name}
          label="product name"
          required
        ></FormInput>
        {console.log(product_name)}
        {console.log(product_specs)}
        {createUI()}
        <div>
          <CustomButton
            onClick={addClick}
            type="button"
            style={{ margin: "14px" }}
          >
            Add More Fields
          </CustomButton>
          <CustomButton type="submit" style={{ margin: "12px" }}>
            Upload Product
          </CustomButton>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductUpload;
```